# Agregar color a un JToggleButton con for

Tags: java

Tengo 12 botones `JToggleButton` y quiero agregarles color, pero no quiero hacerlo uno por uno. Intenté con un for, pero no he logrado hacerlo.
Intenté con:

```
for (int n=1; n<13; n++){
    jToggleButton+n+.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría ahí sería crearme un array de 13 posiciones de tipo JToggleBotton.En cada posición almacenas un botón. Se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
JToggleButton[] arrayBoton = new JToggleButton[13];
for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
arrayBoton[i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
```

De esta forma haces que cada botón dentro del array tenga el fondo verde.